# Not able to drag and drop AjaxControlToolkit's extenders in web form

Tags: asp.net

I have referenced AjaxControltoolkit and after that I have added it to my toolbox of .NET framework. But when I am trying to drag and drop "SlideShowExtender" to my web page, its not dragging there. What is the reason? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could u pls try to close the project and again open it. I think it will refresh and u will able to drag n drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself.
I went in source view and then I had tried to drag and drop. Then it was working.
After that if it also not working then try to "Build solution" and then try the same. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ajaxtoolkit controls in VS2008 are extenders of other controls. Add the parent control first.

or follow this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1559473.aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread12815-ajaxcontroltoolkit-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010-professional.aspx